# Uncountable set of binary functions on the unit square

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $A$ be the unit square $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ and let $S$ be a set of binary functions (possibly uncountable) on the unit square $A$ (i.e, $f \in S$ is a function from $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ to the range  $\{0,1\}$). Assume uniform distribution on A and that for any 2 functions $f,\tilde{f} \in S$ we have $Pr(f \neq \tilde{f}) > 0$. Furthermore, assume that the functions in $S$ are parametrized by a complete space $\Theta$ such that the limit of any sequene $f_{\theta_n} \in S$ is also contained in $S$.

Is the following property true? There exists at least one function $f \in S$ for which for any other function $\tilde{f} \in S\setminus{\{f\}}$ there exists a subset $X \subseteq A$ with positive probability (i.e, $Pr(X)>0$) such that $f(x) > \tilde{f}(x)$ for $x \in X$

Comment: Perhaps I am misreading:  Suppose $f_n(x,y)$ is $1$ iff $x<\frac 1n$. If your $\tilde f$ was $f_k$ Then there is no satisfactory set $X$ for any $f_n$ with $n>k$.  Have I misunderstood something?

Comment: The statment says that there exists at least one such $f$, not that it is satisfied for any $f \in S$. In the example you provided, this is satisfied for $f_1$, as it is 1 in $x \in [1/3, 1/2]$ while all the other functions are zero in this region

Comment: I don;'t understand.  In that region, $f_1$ is *greater* than any other function.  You wanted it to be *less than* any other function.

Comment: I wanted it to be greater than any other function. But if you take $f_n(x,y)$ is $0$ iff $x<1/n$ than this is indeed a counter example if the limit is not in the set $S$. I'll updated the question to include an assumption that the set of functions is parametrized by a complete space (i.e, the limit of any sequence of functions must be in the set $S$)

Comment: What you wrote was that $f(x)>\tilde f(x)$ on some set of positive measure.  That's not "greater than". Anyway, as you remark, it's easy to convert my counterexample to suit the reversed inequality.  I agree that adjoining all the limits breaks my counterexample.